# POPUP Window in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have creating a page where i need to show a div in a popup. I have searched around and only found window.open, that i personally hate, as its a really ugly solution, and causes crosss browser broblems. I have seen floating popups on the web, with a black cross in the right upper hand corner. I think you must create a div, and the JS script will pick up .the div and show it in the floating window. I have searched around alot but could not find a solution. I using Tapestry 5.3.6 . Can anyone show me how to do this..?

Comment: If you are comfortable with JQuery and CSS, you have mentioned your solution in your question. Have a div which contains the cross image, set it to be hidden. On user action on the main page, position this div, and show it with z-index. You can also size your div so that the rest of the screen is hidden. NExt you handle the click on the cross image.

Answer (score 1):

From your description it sounds as though you might be looking for FancyBox:

http://fancybox.net/

There are a lot of tutorials on how to use these JavaScript based overlay type pop-up windows.  The FancyBox homepage shows quite a few examples.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of javascript solutions for this.

Start by looking at 
[Jquery UI](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/)

What you want is called a modal window or dialog

- [Thickbox](http://thickbox.net/)
- [Colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/)

Answer (score 0):

[Jquery Light Box](http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/)

Try this jquery lightbox plugin i think this is what you want...Hope it helps...